# Authorize youtube data api request using google sign in api

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

i am trying to authorize a youtube data request (scope) using google sing in api. Google Sign In works perferct inside my app and i am getting logged in. How do I use the result of the google sign in api to send a request to a youtube data api scope?

My Sign In:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"))
            .build();
    api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(main.getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

This workes fine.

I get a GoogleSignInAccount and a GoogleApiClient from the result.
How do I send a request to youtube for example to add a subscription or get the channel name/id?

Thanks

Keba

Comment: Really? How am I meant to release an app to the play store if google doesn´t want to explain there api to me? When can´t there be an easy way to just login a user and use a simple http request to e.g. subscribe to a channel?!?

Comment: all Oauth2 scopes require the authotise token. so if you send a request for something, you will need to send the token that you have received from the login. As to the "subscribe" button, I have noticed that you must be signed into your account on youtube itself, as it will redirect you there. Was not always so, but has changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ask Google is not able to work with/answer my question, I will now do it myself. (It´s a little embarrassing that a company like google is not able to help developers who ARE working with there apis.)

But thats what I got to work:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"))
            .requestIdToken("APIKEY FROM WEBSITE")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(main.getApplicationContext())
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    api.connect();
```

This will authorise the user, if you want android to show a login window:

```
Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(api);
            main.startActivityForResult(intent, 9001);
```

The result can be used as following:

```
Account account = result.getSignInAccount().getAccount();
```

The Account can now be used to e.g. subscribe to somebody on youtube.

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            Main.main,
            Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"));
    credential.setSelectedAccount(google.getAccount());
    youTube = new YouTube.Builder(
            new NetHttpTransport(),
            new JacksonFactory(),
            credential)
            .setApplicationName("APPNAME")
            .build();
```

The youtube object can now be used for anything you like.

Thanks for this community, even when i am very disappointed about google.

Keba