# How to use Google Sign in to authorize Youtube Data api request?

Tags: java, android, youtube-data-api, google-signin

I am using Google Sign in to authenticate and authorize my users for my app. Now I want to make an api request using Youtube Data api to pull a list of channels that the user might have.

In documentation its says I need an OAuth token for the "Authorizaiton: Bearer"
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#callinganapi

How do I take my account I signed in through Google Sign and get the required OAuth token?

Update: Tried the answer here : [Authorize youtube data api request using google sign in api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638589/authorize-youtube-data-api-request-using-google-sign-in-api) however, it does not work. After tracking down a class and some packages the separate thread I put it on seems to hang and not return anything.

Google Sign In Builder

```
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    boolean isLoggedIn = accessToken != null && !accessToken.isExpired();
    Log.d("frag","login status" + String.valueOf(isLoggedIn));

    scope = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly");
    scopeTwo = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly");
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(scope,scopeTwo)
           // .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();

    googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(), gso);
```

Running the intent for Google Sign and API

```
            api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    .build();
            api.connect();


            Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 21);

            Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(api);
            startActivityForResult(intent,115);
```

Answer (score 0):

see this...
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential

Step 1. get user email

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            email = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            request();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You must pick an account", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //finish();
        }
    } 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

protected void pickUserAccount() {
    String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            accountTypes, true, null, null, null, null);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your phone seems to be missing Google Play Services.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Step 2. get Credential

```
public String getTokenWithEmailOnly(Context context, String email){
    String token = null;

    try {
        token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, email, "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

        TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
        tokenResponse.setAccessToken(token);
        Credential credential = createCredentialWithAccessTokenOnly(tokenResponse);
        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).build();

    } catch (Throwable t) {

    }

    return token;
}

private Credential createCredentialWithAccessTokenOnly(TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
    return (new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod())).setFromTokenResponse(
            tokenResponse);
}
```